# HttpError 403 when requesting Cloud SQL Admin API Client Library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm running a cloud function across 2 different projects. The cloud function is stored in project A and the MySQL instance is in project B.

In order for the cloud function in project A to access the cloud instance and perform import jobs in project B, I've added the service account of the cloud function as a principal in project B and assign the service account with the roles "Cloud SQL Client" and  "Cloud SQL Editor" in project B. I followed this guide here: https://www.cloudquery.io/blog/creating-cross-project-service-accounts-in-gcp

However, when I run the function in project A, I still get this error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/astute-coda-410816/instances/test_database/import?alt=json returned "The client is not authorized to make this request.". Details: "[{'message': 'The client is not authorized to make this request.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notAuthorized'}]">

This is the code I used:

```
import sqlalchemy
from googleapiclient import discovery
import google.auth
import functions_framework
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
credentials, project = google.auth.default()
service = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', credentials=credentials)

#mysql connection
def getconn():
    connector = Connector()
    conn = connector.connect("astute-coda-410816:europe-west2:test_database",
        "pymysql",
        user=os.environ["DB_USER"],
        password=os.environ["DB_PASS"], 
        db="product") 
    return conn

pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://",creator=getconn,)

def move_data(table: str) -> None:
    #list files that need to be imported from gcs
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_data')
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=table)
    files = []
    for blob in blobs:
        files.append(blob.name)

    #import files into mysql
    for i in files:
        instances_import_request_body = {
        "importContext": {
        "uri": f"gs://bucket_data/{i}",
        "kind": "sql#importContext",
        "database": "product",
        "fileType": "CSV",
        "csvImportOptions": {"table": table}
        } 
        }  
        request = service.instances().import_(project="astute-coda-410816", instance="test_database", body=instances_import_request_body)
        response = request.execute()
        process_status = False
        while not process_status:
            resp = service.operations().get(project="astute-coda-410816", operation=response['name']).execute()
            if resp['status'] == "DONE":
                print("finish")
                process_status = True

    
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def transfer(cloudevent):
    #get status of Event method google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob from Cloud Audit Log
    payload = cloudevent.data.get("protoPayload")
    status = payload.get("status")
    if not status: #if status is empty, job was successful and files can be copied over to mysql
        move_data("product_data")
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Did you have activated the CloudSQL API in the project A?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere Yes Cloud SQL Admin API enabled in both projects

Comment: And the non admin API? you don't need the admin API to connect to a database. The Admin API is for creating a database!

Comment: Yes all enabled

Answer (score 2):

The API activation was my first guess but not.

By reading more carefully the error, you are trying to perform an import. This operation require the `cloudsql.instances.import` permission, that is only in the Cloud SQL Admin role (or the project editor role -> a bad practice, don't use this role)

More detail in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/iam-roles

(read the Cloud SQL editor role, it's clearly mentioned that import does not work with it)